# How to create relation between many to many table?

Tags: laravel

***Suppliers table***

```
id | name

1  | supplier1

2  | supplier2
```

***Products table***

```
id | name

1  | product1

2  | product2
```

***Attributes table***

```
id | name

1  | width

2  | heigh

3  | weight

4  | volume
```

***supplier_product table***

```
supplier_id | product_id | price

1           | 1          | 1000

1           | 2          | 1500

2           | 1          | 1100
```

***attribute_product***

```
supplier_id | product_id | attribute_id | value

1           | 1          | 1            | 10

1           | 1          | 2            | 15

1           | 1          | 3            | 20

1           | 2          | 1            | 11

1           | 2          | 2            | 16

2           | 1          | 1            | 10

2           | 1          | 2            | 13
```

- Each supplier has many products
- Each product belongs to many suppliers.
- Each product has many attributes
- Each attribute belongs to many products.

My question is, is the table design correct or is there a more accurate method?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that price and attribute value of same product varies from supplier to supplier, I think the design is correct.

There is no partial dependency or transitive dependency in the tables. Also, these tables are in BCNF and 4NF. And hence the design is efficient enough.